# ¿Cómo volver a mostrar los menús en pycharm?

Tags: menú, pycharm

Normalmente en los editores oculto los menús contextuales en la parte superior del editor y luego los muestro al presionar "alt", sin embargo al hacerlo en pycharm no vuelven a salir al pulsar "alt"
 ¿Cómo puedo volverlo a mostrar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy sensillo activar el menu, solo tienes que ubicar la lupa que esta en la parte superior derecha, escribir la palabra menu y luego activar el menu el la ventana emergente. De igual forma guarde el paso a paso en imagenes para hacerlo mas sencillo.

Espero te sirva. Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡HOLA, en realidad lo he terminado descubriendo solo, pues esa lupa también se oculto, sin embargo, existe una opción cuando incluso la lupa se oculta, es tocar "control + n" lo cual abre el menú de la lupa y luego buscas "show", en la opciones permite mostrarlo de nuevo, muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta!!